# Insert Multiple records in codeigniter using checkboxes

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have 2 input arrays one is checkbox and and another one is textbox

which is my view file

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fee Types</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <?php foreach($types as $key=>$value){?> 
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"  name="type_id[]" />
                <span class="text"><?php echo $value['name'] ?></span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="amount[]" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

which is my controller

```
$data=array(
                    'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
                    'amount'=>$this->input->post('amount'),
                    'type_id'=>$this->input->post('type_id'),
                    'created_date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                    );
                    $this->user->details($data);
```

could anyone tell me how to insert those two arrays as multiple records

Comment: try `$this->input->post('amount[]')` and `$this->input->post('type_id[]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$checkboxes = $this->input->post('type_id[]');
$amounts= $this->input->post('amount[]');

for ($i = 0; $i < count($amounts); $i++) {
   $data = array(
       'id'=> $yourIdPostField,
       'amount'=>$amounts[$i],
       'type_id'=> $checkboxes[$i],
       'created_date'=>date('Y-m-d'),
   );
   $this->user->details($data);
}
```

This is simple way... but maybe your problem is no checkbox post data becouse not checked, if you want that problem then add increment number to your form ...

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fee Types</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <?php foreach($types as $key=>$value){?> 
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"  name="type_id[$key]" />
                <span class="text"><?php echo $value['name'] ?></span>
            </label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="amount[<?php echo $key ?>]" />
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank u for the answer @Martin but i am getting Array to string conversion error

Comment: u are error from my code? Or your version of code? I´m edited name="amount[<?php echo $key ?>]"

Answer (score 0):

$checkboxes = $this->input->post('type_id[]');
$amounts= $this->input->post('amount[]');

$example1 = implode(" ",$checkboxes);

$example2 = implode(" ",$amounts);

Please try this. I hope your problem will be solve.
$checkboxes, $amounts this variables is array so these variable value could not store in your database. So please convert array to string.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?